# Remove Message with MessageID From MessageList

Tags: swift

I have messageList which has all the messages in the chat. I want to remove only one message with the specific messageId but .remove only asks for index as Int. How can I remove that message from the messageList?

```
func deleteMessage(_ message: ChatMessageViewModel) {
        let messageID = message.messageId
        messageList.remove(object: messageID)
        messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
func deleteMessage(_ message: ChatMessageViewModel) {
    let messageID = message.messageId
    messageList.removeAll(where: { $0.messageId == messageID })
    messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```